# html: add link to overlapping images [pic]

Tags: html, css

with a lot of trialnerror and grinding on stack, I (we) have managed to get two images to overlap in a very specific way:

[image: (]

This has been achieved like so:

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container_2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 41.3%;
}

.imageContainer {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.psuedoContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 59%;
}

.psuedoHolder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="component">
      <div class="container_2">
        <div class="imageContainer" style="left: 0;">
          <div class="psuedoContainer">
            <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: left;">
              <img src="./img/img_codemesomething.png" />
              <a href="page_appDev.html"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer" style="right: 0;">
          <div class="psuedoContainer">
            <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: right;">
              <img src="./img/img_recordmesomething.png" />
              <a href="http://google.de"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as you can see, there are two links included into the main two pictures (HTML).

However, only one of the two is working (the google one isnt). This is probably because one images is sort of "above" the other one, and therefore the lower one can never be clicked. At least it cannot be clicked just like it is right now.

How would I go on about adding a link to both images, that, wherever the user clicks, except for in the white part between both images, the user gets directed to a different page?

Thank you :)

Comment: in your code you have 2 open link tags and no closing tags

Comment: @fcalderan sorry. edited. this wasnt the issue however :)

Comment: Link tags are not self closing, but why not move the link up to be the container or just have the link around the image?

Comment: @Pete would you mind showing this to me? :)

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet which outputs something similar to the image, so that others can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the images with the a tag

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container_2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 41.3%;
}

.imageContainer {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.psuedoContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 59%;
}

.psuedoHolder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="component">
      <div class="container_2">
        <div class="imageContainer" style="left: 0;">
          <div class="psuedoContainer">
            <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: left;">
             <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650192/html-add-link-to-overlapping-images-pic/55650729#55650729"> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer" style="right: 0;">
          <div class="psuedoContainer">
            <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: right;">
               <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. I did this but that means that the part that is overlapping, even though you click on the left image, the link from the right image will open... so it isnt quite perfect.. :(

Comment: you want every image to direct to different link ?

Comment: yes, both images (two) need to lead to somewhere else. but because of the overlap, the tip (the sharp edge) of one doesnt work because it is sortof behind the other one even though visibly it isnt...

Comment: i dont know ive tried it even on my vscode  and its working fine the 2 images link to different path

Comment: really? both links work no matter where you click on the image? even when you click on the tips of the edges of each picture?

Comment: can you create the same example in the picture you posted  maybe something else preventing it to not work correctly i even edited the answer 1st link to your question and second to stackoverflow page